# Obtain latest metric from CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to obtain a custom CloudWatch metric.  I don't know up front how often it reports, so I have two problems: what start time do I use and what period to specify.  Is there any way to just get the latest recorded metric, maybe within the last hour or day?  Ideally I don't want to return excessive data points just to discard all but the latest and also don't want to have my period be too large and combine multiple metrics into one or too small and maybe not have data.

Answer (score 0):

**CloudWatch** metrics can have one of two resolutions:

1. Standard resolution, with data having a *one-minute* granularity.
2. High resolution, with data at a granularity of *one second*.

When you publish a custom metric, you can define it as either standard resolution or high resolution. [You can read more about this here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html)

It's up to you to configure how to send your custom metric data to CloudWatch. A [good resource can be found here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-custom-metrics/).

You can install and use a CloudWatch Agent to record your custom metrics, or go the route of making your own script to call the AWS CloudWatch service with the CLI. From a billing perspective, there is no penalty for sending too much custom metric data to the CloudWatch service. You can find out more about the [CloudWatch pricing scheme](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/) here, but I suspect what you're doing will incur a negligible cost.

Comment: The data is already being sent and some of it can actually be 5 minutes (e.g. EC2 without enhanced monitoring).  I know the dimensions, but not the granularity.  How do I query so that I can guarantee I get only the last data point if I don't know the granularity?

Comment: Sounds like using the AWS CloudWatch API might be helpful for this. I know there is an action called GetMetricData - that may be something useful to read about. This should be able to get you the most recent data points for your particular metric.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricData.html

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm already using, sorry I didn't clarify earlier.  I am already getting data back.  `GetMetricData` lets you specify multiple metrics you want to bring back and you have to specify the period.  I don't know if it's reporting every second, every minute, every hour, etc. since CloudWatch lets you customize it.  I just want the latest, but if my period is too small I don't get data back and if it's too large I get multiple data points back.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late but I had the same problem. As it looks like, the `GetMetricDataCommand` has a `MaxDatapoints` parameter which might help you:

```js
const command = new GetMetricDataCommand({
    StartTime: new Date(new Date().setDate(today.getDate() - 30)),
    EndTime: new Date(),
    MetricDataQueries: [/* put your queries here */],
    MaxDatapoints: 1
});
```

Comment: I no longer have a need for this, but does `MaxDatapoints` guarantee you'll get the latest data point or could it be another one including the first in the given date range?

Comment: Good point. I didn't find any indication for that but maybe you could add `ORDER BY` to the SQL statement in `MetricDataQueries`.